# Getting existing data from the server and using it in angular schema form

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have a form that i have created using angular schema form and i have posted it to the server. I now want to take to edit the data i posted. I can get the data like this for isntance

```
app.controller('FormController', function($scope,$http){
   $http.get("data/data.json").then(
      function success(response) {
        $scope.schema = angular.fromJson(response.data);
      },
      function error(response) { /* handle error */ });
   // do other stuff
});
```

How do i populate the data i got from the server to the existing forms that i have created?.

How does angular schema form do this?.

Comment: what is the json response. ?  and can you post your html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing your data. from the $http. you could do this. sorry for the vm. 
im always use controllerAs.

//Edited i added the functionality of the $http for you example.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['schemaForm']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.form = [
        "*",
        {
          "type": "submit",
          "title": "OK"
        }
      ];

      vm.schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Types",
        "properties": {
          "string": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3
          },
          "integer": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "boolean": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "number"
        ]
      };

      vm.model = {boolean: true, string:'abc', integer:1234, number:3.1416};

      vm.loadData = function(){
          $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'data.json'
          }).then(function(response){
            var data = response.data;
            vm.form = data.form;
            vm.schema = data.schema;
            vm.model = data.model;
          });
      };

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="plunker">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.11/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
      <script src="objectPath.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tv4/1.3.0/tv4.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-schema-form/0.8.13/schema-form.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-schema-form/0.8.13/bootstrap-decorator.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
      <form sf-schema="vm.schema" sf-form="vm.form" sf-model="vm.model"></form>

      <pre>{{vm.model}}</pre>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.loadData()">Other Schema</button>

    </body>

  </html>
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "form":
  [
        "*", {
          "type": "submit",
          "title": "OK",
          "style": "btn-success"
        }
      ],
  "schema":{
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Types",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "boolean": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "number"
        ]
      },
    "model":{
        "boolean": true,
        "name": "john",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "age": 34
      }

}
```

this is the new [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/s27ZQxi3jvONAX4nEGOI/)

The key for the edit mode is in your response from the server plus the form and schema, you need to put the vm.model, and remember the model needs to fit whith the schema attributes.

Comment: Hi, I do not have access to the HTML like that since IRS generated by schema form. If you look the schema form repo example, you will see what I mean.

Comment: the example need the FORM json format, and SCHEMA  json  can you share both.

Comment: That's the one. Just grab the schema and form objects from the jsfiddle like environment in the examples

Comment: dont understantd what exaclty not work. ?? if you can share your schema. and your form, can help. i made the plunk based on the official page that you sugges to me. Please shere the schema and format and lets see or even better do a plnkr mock withr your code.

Comment: o i see the pnlkr is not online .. ok let me edit the answer with te code of the plnkr please wait a minute.

Comment: I am using the basic firm from the playground. Just initialize the form using a Json object and let's see how you would do it. Let me get you the link.

Comment: Here is the link http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html. In edit mode of the form, how would I fetch and populate the existing form with data?

Comment: again please check the update anwser. and plunkr hope now is online. is based in the link you give me.

Comment: i made an update of the code of the answer and plnkr ... please try out. Hope now this really help.